Change icon of .exe file ALSO for taskbar and top of window IF that .exe file does not have any icon yet
So I am able to successfully change icon to any .exe file that already have its own icon
Using resource hacker
And I am talking about icon inside folder icon that is displayed for program when it is opened
Yet I can only change icon of what is displayed inside folder of .exe file which did not have its own icon
Basically this Font Builder
https://github.com/andryblack/fontbuilder
As you can see icon inside folder is changed and works perfectly fine
But program icon on taskbar and on top let of program window icon stays as unknown/default.
Screenshot here:

And so I wonder is it even possible using resource hacker or any other way to change icons in top left window program part and taskbar?
I mean if someone knows other program or way to do it i am all open for ideas.

If you wish to change the icon that is built-in to an .exe file,
there are two ways for that:

If you can compile the product, replace the icon-file that it uses,
which is usually of the .ico type.
Hack the .exe and replace the icon inside it.

A product that can help with the second method is the free
Resource Hacker:


And that's the issue here
This program i wanna set icon for have no icon at all
And i ask if that is possible to do any way possible?

I've downloaded the sources, and to my surprise this Qt program has absolutely no icon. I looked at the sources, and there is not one .ico file, the sources don't contain a call to QWindow::setIcon and there's not even a resource-file .rc. On my computer the executable FontBuilder.exe has some default icon that's different than yours. Conclusion: Setting an icon would require changes to the sources and re-compilation, and I don't know if this is worth the bother. You might signal this to the developer, although he hasn't answered in 2023.

If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

OK Thx
As much as i want to changed it
More important thing for me was i missing something/doing something wrong
Or is there lack of means for me to do what i want
So since fault is not on my side i gonna live with that default/lack of icon
Again THX for clarifying
